# Getting the q-item-label text

Tags: node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have this code using Quasar/VueJS. What I want to do is update the dropdown text label (`keyDropDownLabel`) based on the selected `<q-item-label>`.

So in this example below, I want the `newLabelGoesHere` part to be `Key 1/2/3`, depending on which was clicked.

```
<q-btn-dropdown stretch flat :label="keyDropDownLabel">
  <q-list>
    <q-item v-for="n in 3" :key="`x.${n}`" clickable v-close-popup tabindex="0">
      <q-item-section @click="keyDropDownLabel = 'newLabelGoesHere'">
        <q-item-label>Key {{ n }}</q-item-label>
        <q-item-label caption>1234567890</q-item-label>
      </q-item-section>
    </q-item>
  </q-list>
</q-btn-dropdown>
```

Anyone help please??

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the **q-item-section** **click** method like below:

```
<q-item-section @click="keyDropDownLabel('Key'+n)">
```